# This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active. Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, transactions

I am receiving the error `This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.` on a Django 1.8 install.

I've tried wrapping it in both with `transaction.atomic():` as well as creating an exception for `IntegrityError`

Here's my code:

```
item = Item.objects.filter(item_id = data['item_id'])[:1][0]
iserializer = ItemSerializer(item, data=data, partial=True)
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        if iserializer and iserializer.is_valid():
            iserializer.save()
except IntegrityError:
    pass
```

What could be causing it? Why is my exception handling not working to keep this error from being received?

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/vagrant/client/venv/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 186, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "/home/vagrant/client/venv/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 880, in update
    instance.save()
  File "/vagrant/client/client/items/models.py", line 45, in save
    transaction.commit()
  File "/home/vagrant/client/venv/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 42, in commit
    get_connection(using).commit()
  File "/home/vagrant/client/venv/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 172, in commit
    self.validate_no_atomic_block()
  File "/home/vagrant/client/venv/bin/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 322, in validate_no_atomic_block
    "This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.")
TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.
```

Comment: Please fix your code indentation - it's not valid Python as it is - and post more details - specially, the full original traceback.

Comment: I think its a `TransactionManagementError`. Is it raised on the "save" line? And wouldn't that just mean that you can't do it in an atomic transaction? A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: It is a TransactionManagementError. I'll post the traceback.

And my apologies for the code indentation being off - I edited the text in a word processor to keep client details anonymous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the traceback, it looks like you're overriding the model's `save()` method and explicitly calling `transaction.commit()`.

```
File "/vagrant/client/client/items/models.py", line 45, in save
  transaction.commit()
```

As the error indicates, you can't do that inside an atomic block since the block is expecting to do that itself.

More fundamentally, the error here is in mixing the high-level transactions API (`transaction.atomic()`) and the low-level transactions API (`transaction.commit()`). They are meant to be alternatives to each other, not used together.

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#low-level-apis):

> Always prefer `atomic()` if possible at all. It accounts for the idiosyncrasies of each database and prevents invalid operations.
>   The low level APIs are only useful if you’re implementing your own transaction management.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right. I discovered this a couple hours after posting it. I'll give you the answer.